# how to access single .mdf file across multiple services and projects

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, localdb

I have Windows service which is gathering data and storing it on to the .mdf file which is a local database. I also have MVC application which reads this same .mdf file and displays values on UI Portal. I am facing problem running both applications simultaneously. whenever i try to connect the second application to already connected .mdf file i am getting error saying its already used by another application or present on unc share

Comment: Maybe you should describe the problem, explain what you are doing, show some code etc. Currently you have no question so nobody can answer.

Comment: If you use SQL server many things can access it, what specifically is the issue

Comment: An `.mdf` file is a **SQL Server** database, and as the name implies, it's really a **server-based** database solution. So the way to do this is: put your database **on the server** and don't fiddle around with free-floating `.mdf` files, and connect to that server from your various applications to use a common set of data

Comment: Everyone is correct, rather referring the .mdf file, host it on the sql server instance, and then can be used by n no of application.

Comment: You can use same `.mdf` by using it as reference in other projects. However that's not a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multi-user simultaneous access you should use full version of SQL Server, for example, `SQL Server Express` that is also gratis.